# Dialog with command buttons Windows Phone 7, How?

Tags: windows-phone-7, command, alert, dialog

i'm looking at design templates for windows phone 7 pdf, and at dialog boxes page,i'm interested on dialog with command buttons. it didn't use messagebox, it listed there as dialog boxes. anyone know where i can find information about it ?, a sample codes will be nice.

this is what i mean

http://twitpic.com/4og7tz

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the templates, with full XAML code, [in this CodePlex project](http://wp7designtemplates.codeplex.com/). This has been created by the those behind the Metro UI, so it all adheres to the true Metro guidelines.